# calculate degree of friendship

Tags: mysql, algorithm, data-structures, social-networking

I have created following data model for storing friends of a user -

Database - **MySQL**

```
tbl_user [ user_id - pk ]    
tbl_user_friend [ inviter_id - fk, friend_id - fk,  status - 1/2/3 ]   

status = 2 => friend , = 1 => invite ...

select friend_id from tbl_user_friend where inviter_id = <logged_in_id> and status = 2
UNION
select inviter_id from tbl_user_friend where friend_id = <logged_in_id> and status = 2
```

Now I need to categorize them into 1st, 2nd , 3rd degree connection on searching.

**An option I can come up with  -**

```
Convert above data into Graph and do BFS search.
Level of a node in BFS traversal will be its degree of connection.
```

- option 1) Use MySQL OQGraph Engine for this but this requires a
  special build of Mysql
- option 2) use Stored Procedures in MySQL to do BFS

Can you suggest some more algorithm/model here than one I stated already.

Thanks